# Why is ousia translated as substance? Should it be?

Tags: metaphysics, terminology, aristotle

From Aristotle's *Metaphysics*, translation Reeve 2016, Z1:

> What is being?---is just the question, What is substance?

This statement is a lot more obvious in Greek:

> *Ousia* is a noun formed from the present participle *ousa* of the verb *einai* ("to be"). "Substance" is the traditional translation.
>   (note 58, pg 272)

(Of course Aristotle has a lot more to say about why the two questions are the same. But surely etymology has *something* to do with his word choice.)

If I understand Aristotle correctly (not likely), a substance is a combination of form and matter (aka a hylomorphism). Now anything with both form and matter seems to me to be just *a* thing, an object, a being. And it also seems like any thing, object, or being just *is* matter in a certain form, and therefore a substance. Then it seems like all these words mean the same thing. If these alternatives exist, "substance" seems to me to be a bizarre choice to translate *ousia*.

Who first translated *ousia* as "substance", and why did they choose that word?

And can I rephrase Aristotle's equation as

> What is being?---is just the question, What is a being?

(which has the virtue of maintaining the etymological tie between *einai* and *ousia*) or

> What is being?---is just the question, What is a thing?

and still keep his meaning intact?

Comment: [Latin substantia](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/substantia) is formed from substō, to stand under, to exist, in the same way that ousia is formed from einai. It does mean being or essence. Why is it a bizarre choice for translation (regardless of Aristotle)?

Comment: @Conifold It sacrifices the etymological connection between einai and ousia making the connection between being and substance obscure, and it replaces a common word, about which I have lots of intuitions, with a technical one, about which I have very few.

Comment: In medieval Latin it was an obvious connection and a common word. And it is highly unlikely that your intuitions match Aristotle's from a different culture of over two millenia ago, let alone the technical sense he gave to "ousia" in his philosophy. So "substance" might be a blessing in disguise.

Comment: That makes sense; translating eudaimonia as "happiness" used to cause me trouble, because I couldn't separate Aristotle's technical usage from my intuitions. But Aristotle wasn't above coining terms ("the what-it-is"). So I guess my real question is, What intuition was Aristotle drawing on when he chose ousia as the technical term for the subject of predication? But I should open a new question for that. @Conifold: thanks

Comment: I'm with Heidegger, who comments that most of our philosophical problems come from confusing Being with beings. In the language here this would be confusing substance (form and matter) with Being. I share your confusion over the translation of 'ousia' but am not sure whether the issue is the translation or Aristotle himself. . .

Comment: This book may help, Alfredo Ferrarin, "Hegel and Aristotle",  https://archive.org/details/HegelAndAristotle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There are several senses in which a thing may be said to be, as we pointed out. [*Met*, Book Z, 1028a9]
>
> there are many senses in which a thing is said to be, but all refer to
>   one starting-point; some things are said to be because they are substances, others because they are affections of substance, others because they are a process towards substance, or destructions or privations or qualities of substance, or productive or generative of substance, or of things which are relative to substance, or negations of some of these things or of substance itself [[*Met*, Book Gamma, 1003b](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0052%3Abook%3D4%3Asection%3D1003b)].

Thus, following [Franz Brentano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franz_Brentano)'s dissertation : [On the Several Senses of Being in Aristotle (1862), page 3](http://reader.digitale-sammlungen.de/de/fs1/object/goToPage/bsb10234887.html?pageNo=5) :

> The various sorts of being which are here enumerated can be reduced to four kinds:
>
> > (1) Being which has no existence whatever outside the understanding
> >     (privation, negation);
> >
> > (2) The being of movement and of generation and corruption (process toward
> >     substance, destruction);
> >
> > (3) Being which has complete but dependent existence (affections of substance,
> >     qualities, things productive and generative);
> >
> > (4) The being of the substances (*ousia*).

And see [*Cat*, 5, 2a13](http://classics.mit.edu/Aristotle/categories.1.1.html) :

> A *substance* —that which is called a substance most strictly, primarily,
>   and most of all [[protai ousiai (πρῶται οὐσίαι), "primary substances"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ousia)] — is that which is neither said of a subject nor in a subject, e.g. the individual man or the individual horse.

---

*Substance* is from Latin : [substantia](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/substantia) :

> From *substāns*, present active participle of *substō* (“stand under; exist”), from sub + *stō* (“stand”).

See also [hypostasis](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hypostasis#Latin) :

> From ecclesiastical Latin *hypostasis*, from Ancient Greek ὑπόστασις (hupóstasis, “sediment, foundation; substance, existence, essence”), from ὑπό (hupó) + στάσις (stásis, “standing”).

And see : John Marenbon, [Boethius](https://books.google.it/books?id=UsL8tvUkZqoC&printsec=frontcover), Oxford UP (2003), page 71 :

> Boethius, however, goes out of his way to link his definition of *persona* to
>   an Aristotelian understanding of *hupostasis*. He is helped by a linguistic accident. In order to explain this, it is useful to introduce a new term — one obviously different from any word Boethius himself uses — for things that
>   belong to Aristotle’s first category (*ousia*): I shall accordingly speak of ‘first-category things/individuals/universals’.
>
> The linguistic accident consists in the fact that the usual, Latin translation of *hupostasis* was *substantia*. But *substantia* was also the Latin word used by some, including Boethius himself, as the word for first-category things.

---

---

For a linguistic analysis regarding Ancient Greek use of the terms regarding being (*εἶναι*, *οὐσία*) see :

- Charles Kahn, [Essays on Being](https://books.google.it/books?id=DxE6zOaaGyIC&printsec=frontcover), Oxford University Press (2009).

For a philosophical analysis, from the point of view of modern formal logic, see :

- Jaakko Hintikka, [The Varieties of Being in Aristotle](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-94-009-4780-1_4), into : Simo Knuuttila & Jaakko Hintikka (editor), [The Logic of Being : Historical Studies](https://books.google.it/books?id=9fjwCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA81), Reidel (1986).

Comment: For this, you have to inquire the [Medieval Latin translations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recovery_of_Aristotle) and the Latin commentary of the Roman [Boethius (477–524 AD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boethius) : [*In Categorias Aristotelis*](https://la.wikisource.org/wiki/In_categorias_Aristotelis_commentaria).